# Move localStorage to different page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How do add a variable to localStorage in a function with an if-statement, and then move to a different page via location.assign where the information is inserted via innerHTML? I tried with setItem and I know that you can loop through the string (it's supposed to be a string, so no need for JSON.stringify), but I only want to add it once. The variable comes from a text area that exists in a form on page 2 and that should be sent to page 1. Here's my code:

```
function test () {

    x = document.forms["users"]["fname"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="") {
        document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = "Please make your contribution.";
        return false;

        }else{

        localStorage.contribution = x;
        location.assign("page1.html");

        localStorage.getItem(x);
        document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = x;

        }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to "send" the variable - the localStorage content is shared across the domain. mydomain.com/page1.html and mydomain.com/path/goes/here/page42.html should all access the same storage. On the other hand, I notice you never actually store something in localStorage - you need to first do `localStorage.setItem("myValue", value)` to be able to then go `localStorage.getItem("myValue")`

Comment: Okay, thanks. The main problem was that I couldn't show it with innerHTML and now it works, but only after I removed the button which linked to a different function that pointed to the same location as localStorage pointed to. It seems that you can't use the same location for both localStorage and innerHTML.

Comment: Actually, I just realised something - you're calling `localStorage.getItem(x)` but you never actually assign the output to anything, so even if it was being retrieved correctly, it's just discarded afterwards. You need to do something like `var fetchedItem = localStorage.getItem(x)` and then `document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = fetchedItem` to show it.